# A hypothesis: Integral of $f^n(x)$ is monotonic as $n$ reaches infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

When I'm solving some analysis questions I discovered some interesting phenomenons. I can't prove it or give any counterexamples so I'm seeking help.

If $f(x)$ is a continuous, monotonic, non-negative function on $[a,b]$, then sequence
$$\left\{\int_a^bf^n(x)\mathrm{d}x\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$
is monotonic, or at least starting from some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ it is.

If someone can prove it or give a counterexample. Thanks!

($f^n(x)$ means $[f(x)]^n$.)

Comment: What is $f^3(x)$? Is it $f(x)f(x)f(x)$? Is it $f(f(f(x)))$?

Comment: @ajotatxe It is $f(x)f(x)f(x)$.

Comment: I do not think it is true as $f(x)$ may admit values greater than $1$ and less than $1.$

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Yes, but finding a counterexample is just hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your hypothesis is correct.

First if $\max\limits_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\leqslant1$, then $f^{n}\geqslant f^{n+1}$ hence $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f^{n}(x)\,dx\geqslant\int_{a}^{b}f^{n+1}(x)\,dx$.

Now we assume $\max\limits_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)=M>1$, let $a_{n}=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f^{n}(x)\,dx$. So we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=M>1$, which means $a_{n}$ is eventually monotonic.

By Cauchy-Schwarz,$$a_{n}=\int_{a}^{b}f^{n}(x)\,dx=\int_{a}^{b}f^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(x)f^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(x)\,dx\leqslant\left( \int_{a}^{b}f^{n-1}(x)\,dx\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \int_{a}^{b}f^{n+1}(x)\,dx\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}.$$Thus $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ is increasing and $$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\dfrac{\int_{a}^{b}f^{n+1}(x)\,dx}{\int_{a}^{b}f^{n}(x)\,dx}\leqslant M\dfrac{\int_{a}^{b}f^{n}(x)\,dx}{\int_{a}^{b}f^{n}(x)\,dx}=M.$$So the limit exists.

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=M$ is because$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}=M=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\dfrac{\log\frac{a_{2}}{a_{1}}+\ldots+\log\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}}{n}}\cdot e^{\dfrac{\log a_{1}}{n}}=e^{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\log\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}.$$

Comment: It's not clear that $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n$ exists, nor is it clear that $\liminf a_{n+1}/a_n > 1$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this might be correct! You get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=M$, because $a_n\approx M^n$ as $n\to\infty$ (and this is because $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\int_a^b{f^n(x)\mathrm{d}x})^\frac{1}{n}=M$) ? That's brilliant.

Comment: Does it mean that the monotonicity of $f(x)$ is totally useless? I don't see any use of it.

Comment: Wait, can I actually get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{M^n}=1$ from $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n^{1/n}}{M}=1$? I don't think so..

Comment: No, $a_n=\int\limits_0^2x^{n}\,dx ={1\over n+1}2^{n+1}$

Comment: @Hydrogen37 I have edited the answer again. I’m afraid that the monotonicity of $f(x)$ is not necessary. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: @mio Thanks! Now I fully understood it. I also believe that monotonicity of $f(x)$ is not necessary. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The monotonicity is not essential, but may help writing the answer. Let $f(b)>1>f(a).$ For $c$ such that  $f(c)=1$ we have $$a_{n+1}-a_n=-\int\limits_a^c[1-f(x)][f(x)]^n\,dx+\int\limits_c^b[f(x)-1][f(x)]^n\,dx\to \infty$$ as the first term tends to $0$ and the second one to $\infty.$

Comment: But this doesn't mean $(a_n)$ is not eventually monotonic.

Comment: OP is asking if the sequence is **eventually** increesing/decreasing.

Comment: Thanks, but it is a counterexample when and only when for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, there exists $s,t>k$ such that $a_s>a_k$ and $a_t<a_k$.